# Getting error "Local variable referenced before assignment" - Python

Tags: python

The following code gives me error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'summary' referenced before assignment"

```
@app.route('/analyse',methods=['GET'])
def analyse():

rawtext = request.args.get('raw_text')

blob = TextBlob(rawtext)

received_text2 = blob

blob_sentiment  =   str(TextBlob(rawtext).sentiment.polarity)
blob_subjectivity = str(TextBlob(rawtext).sentiment.subjectivity)

number_of_tokens = len(list(blob.words))
# Extracting Main Points

nouns = list()

for word, tag in blob.tags:
    if tag == 'NN':
        nouns.append(word.lemmatize())
        len_of_words = len(nouns)
        rand_words = random.sample(nouns,len(nouns))
        final_word = list()
        for item in rand_words:
            word = Word(item).pluralize()
            final_word.append(word)
            summary = final_word




resp = make_response(jsonify({'error':'false', 'Nouns':summary, 'sentiment':blob_sentiment, 'subjectivity': blob_subjectivity}))
resp.status_code = 200
resp.mimetype = 'application/json'
return resp
```

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=99)

Comment: If your variable `tag` is never `'NN'`, `summary` will never be set. Or, if your `rand_words` list is empty, that's another case where `summary` won't get set. Or, `blob.tags` could have no data in which case the entire for loop wouldn't run and `summary` again wouldn't get set. Try looking into those and doing some debugging there

Comment: Thanks, let me look into this

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it appears that one of two things are going on:

- Either there's no tag == 'NN', which means **summary** will never be created.
- Or `rand_words` is empty, which means there's never going to cycle.

In both cases the problem looks like it's not reaching the part where you declare **summary**, my opinion would be to debug that segment of the code and detect where's failing.